SQL query find and display social network related users and their relation type
I have been asked this question in an interview and I couldn't finish it. I am not not sure how to have the right query even after the interview.
Below is the question, sample data and my attempt.
Question: A social network under development needs a query that returns all profiles and the types of their relationships with each other.
The result should have the following columns:  profile | %related_profile_1% .. %related_profile_N%
The result should be sorted in ascending order by profile
Table definitions
CREATE TABLE profiles (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE relations (
  profile_id INT NOT NULL,
  related_profile_id INT NOT NULL,
  type ENUM('family','friends','acquaintances'),
  FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (related_profile_id) REFERENCES profiles(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (profile_id, related_profile_id) 
);

-- sample data 
+----+---------------+
| id | username      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | msilverstone0 |
|  2 | cbedinn1      |
|  3 | polivi2       |
|  4 | giacobassi3   |
|  5 | mlorence4     |
|  6 | aayliffe5     |
|  7 | nhollyard6    |
|  8 | oorrett7      |
|  9 | duccello8     |
| 10 | kgerardin9    |
+----+---------------+


sample data for relations table 
+------------+--------------------+---------------+
| profile_id | related_profile_id | type          |
+------------+--------------------+---------------+
|          1 |                  2 | friends       |
|          1 |                  4 | friends       |
|          1 |                  5 | acquaintances |
|          1 |                  7 | acquaintances |
|          1 |                  8 | friends       |
|          1 |                  9 | acquaintances |
|          2 |                  3 | acquaintances |
|          2 |                  4 | acquaintances |
|          2 |                  5 | acquaintances |
|          2 |                  6 | friends       |
|          2 |                  8 | family        |
|          2 |                  9 | acquaintances |

My effort
SELECT p.username AS profile,
       GROUP_CONCAT(r2.username, ' (', r.type, ')') AS related_profiles
FROM profiles p
LEFT JOIN relations r ON r.profile_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN profiles r2 ON r.related_profile_id = r2.id
GROUP BY p.username
ORDER BY p.username;

**Resultset **

But I am looking for result in the following format

I'm using MySQL.
